How to populate a field in MongoEngine subdocument in Flask-Admin
I have a flask-admin project, and this is the mongoengine docs I am working on:
class UserEmailTemplatesCategoriesTranslations(mongo_db.EmbeddedDocument):
    language_code = mongo_db.StringField()
    text = mongo_db.StringField()


class UserEmailTemplatesCategories(mongo_db.DynamicDocument):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'user_email_templates_categories',
        'indexes': [
            {'fields': ('category', 'subcategory'), 'unique': True}
        ]
    }

    category = mongo_db.StringField(choices=em_templates.get_category_names(), required=True)
    subcategory = mongo_db.StringField(required=True)
    default_text = mongo_db.StringField(default=None)
    text_translation = mongo_db.ListField(mongo_db.EmbeddedDocumentField(UserEmailTemplatesCategoriesTranslations))
    is_active = mongo_db.BooleanField(default=True)


I have been trying to figure out how I can turn UserEmailTemplatesCategoriesTranslations language_code field into a SelectField, I figured it out after reading this: Trying to add form_widget_args to sub document form in mongoengine modelview
so I applied it like this and it worked:
    form_subdocuments = {
        'text_translation': {
            'form_subdocuments': {
                None: {
                    'form_overrides': {
                        'language_code': SelectField
                    },
                    'form_args': {
                        'language_code': {'choices': []}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }

but now I am facing a new dilemma which I have failed to find a solution for, I have this code that brings me a list of languages:
def get_language_choices():
    retrieved_languages = consumer_models.Languages.objects().only('language_code', 'language_name').order_by(
        'language_name')

    return [
        (
            obj.language_code,
            f"{str(obj.language_code).upper()} - {str(obj.language_name).title()}"
        ) for obj in retrieved_languages
    ]

I want this code to be applied to language_code, on create and edit, but I can't seem to figure how to do it, I have searched but to no avail. Its working on fields that are not an part of an embedded document, but I can't figure out how to make it work on fields inside a List of Embedded documents
